# Dynamically added listitem and menuitem links not working

Tags: c#, hyperlink, asp.net-4.0

I am trying to create a link to a page that is passed the path of a file uploaded in a FileUpload control. This link needs to be added to a list. The page is works perfectly fine when I hardcode in links to the html. However, when I try to create a link dynamically I always receive the error:

> The resource cannot be found.
>
> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /WebForm1.apsx

I have tried both using an asp:Menu and an asp:BulletedList with a hyperlink display mode. Below is the html.

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" Width="600" ToolTip="Choose the Trade Blotter Source File to Upload" />
<asp:Button ID="UploadButton" runat="server" Text="Upload File Data"     OnClick="UploadButton_Click" ToolTip="Upload the File Data" />
<asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false"
    IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Items>
        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/WebForm1.aspx?param=hubba hubba" Text="without fileupload" />
    </Items>
</asp:Menu>

<asp:BulletedList ID="BulletedList1" DisplayMode="Hyperlink" runat="server"  >
    <asp:ListItem Value="~/Webform1.aspx?param=New York">New York</asp:ListItem>
   
    </asp:BulletedList>
  <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

When the uploadbutton is clicked, this code runs,

```
protected void UploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string s = FileUpload1.FileName;
        string url = "~/WebForm1.apsx?param=" + s;
        
        ListItem li = new ListItem(s, url);
        BulletedList1.Items.Add(li);
        
        MenuItem mu = new MenuItem(s, null, null, url);
        NavigationMenu.Items.Add(mu);

    }
```

Both the BulletedList and Menu have links added to them after the upload button is pressed, but both links lead to the error above. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Chris

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo on this line:

```
string url = "~/WebForm1.apsx?param=" + s;
```

It should have been

```
string url = "~/WebForm1.aspx?param=" + s;
```